# Why do i have to precompile assets locally when using an asset host?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, cdn

I am using an asset host (AWS Cloudfront) for my Rails application:

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.asset_host = "xxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net"
```

During my deployment on my CI service I precompile assets:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

And then push those generated assets to the S3 bucket that serves as the origin of the Cloudfront distribution.

**Note**: I don't include the precompiled assets in my final docker image that is eventually deployed.

Now when I start the server and try to access it - I receive the error:

> application.css is not present in the asset pipeline

I know that there are multiple questions on Stackoverflow with this specific error message. But **I tried everything** e.g. like setting `config.assets.compile = true/false` but the only thing that made it work was **including the precompiled assets in the build** (final docker image).

So now I am asking myself: Do I have to always include the assets locally although I am using an asset host?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the way `asset pipeline` resolve asset path that it'll look up the `fingerprinting` of the asset file first (which be generated by the rake task `precompile`) then map to `asset_host` (if any), if there's no `fingerprinting` map to the asset then it'll throw exception, it does not check on your `asset_host`.

if you don't include the precompiled assets in your docker image, your rails app in docker container can't find asset files since there's no `fingerprinting` be generated in that container.

so yes, you have to.

however, you can bypass the `asset pipeline` by add a forward slash before the asset path or add `skip_pipeline: true`, in your case, you already generate the fingerprinting and push those files to your asset host so you can bypass ,for example the `application.css`, like this `stylesheet_link_tag '/application-{fingerprinting}.css'`, but obviously it's not the good choice since you need to do this for all files.

Comment: Thank you really much for your input. Do you know if there is any official documentation on this?

Comment: @zarathustra read code, the code tell everything, here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb, and here: https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/blob/master/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb

Comment: This may have changed in the current version of rails. It doesn't seem like you need to include the static assets on the app servers anymore - just the ".sprockets-manifest-randomhex.json". That file maps 'appliaction.css' to the filename that includes the fingerprint. As long as the sprockets manifest is present, then rails can generate the proper URL to the fingerprinted asset using asset_host as the base.